# Dependent futures

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, future

Starting playing with Scala futures, I get stuck with dependent futures.

Let's get a example. I search for places and get a `Future[Seq[Place]]`. For each of theses places, I search for the closest subway stations (the service resurns a `Future[List[Station]]`).

I would write this:

```
Place.get()
.map { places =>
    places.map { place =>
        Station.closestFrom(place).map { stations =>
            SearchResult(place, stations)
        }
    }
}
```

That thing will make me get a `Future[Seq[Future[SearchResult]]]`... which is... not what I would have expected.

What did I miss to get a `Future[Seq[SearchResult]]` ?

Thanks for all,

Alban

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing two `Future` concepts in your solution: `flatMap` and `Future.sequence`

To explain each:

`flatMap` is like `map` except instead of giving it a function from `future.map(A => B)` you give it a function from `future.flatMap(A => Future[B])`. This way you can chain Futures together.

`Future.sequence` is a helper function that combines a list of futures to a future of a list: `Seq[Future[A]] => Future[Seq[A]]`

Using these two features of the `Future` API we can change your answer to be:

```
Place.get().flatMap { places =>
    Future.sequence(places.map { place =>
        Station.closestFrom(place).map { stations =>
            SearchResult(place, stations)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Short version

Working with futures is generaly easier using for-comprehension rather than directly map/flatMap. In your situation it should look like this:

```
for {places        <- Place.get()
     searchResults <- Future.traverse(places)(place => for (stations <- Station.closestFrom(place))
                                                       yield SearchResult(place,stations)
                                              )
} yield searchResults
```

### Detailed Version

`Future` being a monad, it offers you several ways to chain your operations.

- If you want to apply an 'regular' function `f : A => B` to what's inside the box `myfuture : Future[A]`, indeed `map` is the way to get a `Future[B]`. But in the present situation `Station.closestFrom` a does not give you a `List[Stattion]` but a `Future[List[Station]]`.
- If you want to apply a monadic operation `h : A => Future[B]` or chain several of them (here `Places.get` and `Station.closestFrom`), `flatMap` is the way to go. Apply `h` to a `Future[A]` gives you a `Future[B]`.
- If you want to apply a monadic operation `h : A => Future[B]` to a collection like a `places : Seq[A]`, you should use `Future.traverse : Seq[A] => (A => Future[B]) => Future[Seq[B]]`.

Furthermore, Scala's for-compresention is just syntactic sugar for flatMap/map so instead of writing complex code using those directly you can use a clean and clear for loop. The loop:

```
for { variable1 <- f1
      variable2 <- f2
} yield expression
```

is equivalent to (without optimisations) :

```
f1.flatMap( variable1 => f2.map(variable2 => expression))
```

Don't hesitate to use for-comprehension, it really helps.

Comment: Nice! But your exemple does not seem to compile "as is". The `place` variable is not defined... am I right? But it is quickly working adding a `place <- places` between the two lines.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for that, the new version should be ok this time.